# Clearpage when only the first or second line of a new paragraph fits on the previous page

Tags: spacing, sectioning, clearpage

I want to make it so the first line of a new paragraph will automatically trigger a `\clearpage` so that the first line in the new paragraph isn't standing alone on the previous page.
Is this possible, or do I have to manually add `\clearpage`'s when I'm proofreading?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright,hidelinks]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[%
    bindingoffset=0.5in,%
    left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,%
    footskip=.5in,%
    marginparwidth=2.2cm,
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\linespread{1,2}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

this line is the line that i want to begin on the next page automatically. its contents are unknown, maybe its to conclude on the written blindtext? Could be something else like the start of a recipe, anyway, its a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long sentence
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The penalty for breaking after one line is `\clubpenalty` so set that to 10000 to prevent a break there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright,hidelinks]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[%
    bindingoffset=0.5in,%
    left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,%
    footskip=.5in,%
    marginparwidth=2.2cm,
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}
\linespread{1,2}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\clubpenalty=10000

this line is the line that i want to begin on the next page automatically. its contents are unknown, maybe its to conclude on the written blindtext? Could be something else like the start of a recipe, anyway, its a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long sentence
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know where I would need to look to find that information. Note to self: It also works by putting it in the preamble, I'm guessing it then affects the document globally instead of just locally?

Comment: After having read a bit around for `\clubpenalty` the majority states its generally a bad idea to change such parameters globally, what are your thoughts on that?

Comment: yes it's a sledgehammer and so can cause some damage if you hit the wrong thing. Specifically it prevents a page break _there_ but does nothing to allow one anywhere else, so if there is not enough stretch on the page to allow a break before the paragraph or after that line, then there will be no legal break point and tex will just take some sub-optimal choice, see `widows-and-orphans` package for  more gentle but not automatic approach. @L.Nielsen